# what's the relationship with log(sum) and sum(log)?

Tags: logarithms

hi I'm a little confused about the log(sum) function and sum(log) function. In special, what's the relationship between these two terms?
$$
-\log \sum_{i}a_i\sum_i b_i
$$

$$
-\sum_i\log(a_i+b_i)
$$

---

thanks for the comment from @hardmath. here is the original question:

given a negative log-likelihood of an observation set:
$$
\mathbf{L}=-\sum_{i,j}\log(\pi_a M_{i,j}+\pi_bN_{i,j})
$$
where C is the constant parameter. $\pi_a$+$\pi_b$=1 are proportion of the two component, given the instance $O_{ij}$.

$\bf{Lemma 1}$
$$
-\log\sum_{k=1}^Kf_k(x)=\min_{\Phi(x)\in \Delta_+}\sum_{k=1}^K\{\Phi_k(x)[\log\Phi_k(x)-log(f_k(x)]\} \\
s.t. \sum\Phi_k(x)=1, \Phi_k(x)\in (0,1)
$$

$\bf{proof}$
$$
RHS=\sum_{k=1}^K\Phi_k(x)\log\frac{\Phi_k(x)}{f_k(x)} \\
>=\sum_{k=1}^K\Phi_k(x)\log\frac{\sum_{k=1}^K\Phi_k(x)}{\sum_{k=1}^Kf_k(x)}(log-sum\ inequality) \\
=-\log\sum_{k=1}^Kf_k(x)(\sum\Phi_k(x)=1)
$$

Let:
$$
\mathit{C}=\sum_{i,j}\Phi^{i,j}_a(\log\Phi^{i,j}_a-\log(\pi_aM_{i,j}))+\Phi^{i,j}_b(\log\Phi^{i,j}_B-\log(\pi_bN_{i,j}))
$$
given the constraint, that for each $(i,j)$, $\Phi^{i,j}_a+\Phi^{i,j}_b=1$

Then $\textbf{how to prove:}$

Minimize $C$ equals minimize $L$ ?

following lemma1, we have 
$$
\min C=-\log\sum(\pi_aM_{i,j})-\log\sum(\pi_bN_{i,j})
$$
then the next step is how to prove the relationship between $\min C$ and $L$?

Comment: this is related to the so called "log-sum commutativity" lemma. I tried to relate it with the negative log likelihood function for equation comparison.

Comment: $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)\neq\log(a+b)$

Comment: If you want to relate these expressions, more context is needed, e.g. the hypotheses of your "log-sum commutativity" lemma if it applies to your Question.

Comment: thanks @hardmath , I have modified my post in more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, I forgot one constraint, that is, for each i,j, we have $\Phi^{i,j}_a+\Phi^{i,j}_b=1$. So this should be straightforward, i.e.,

for each coordinate $(i,j)$, $\Phi^{i,j}_a+\Phi^{i,j}_b=1$, then,
$$
C_{i,j}=\Phi^{i,j}_a(\log\Phi^{i,j}_a−\log(\pi_aM_{i,j}))+\Phi^{i,j}_b(\log\Phi^{i,j}_b−\log(\pi_bN_{i,j}))
$$
e.g., $\pi_a=\pi^g,\pi_b=\pi^u,M_{i,j}=Normal_{i,j}(O_{i,j}|\theta),N_{i,j}=\frac{1}{256}$

Apply $\bf{Lemma\ 1}$,

$$
\min C_{i,j}=-\log(\pi_aM_{i,j}+\pi_bN_{i,j})
$$
integrating out RHS of $C$,
$$
\min C=\sum_{i,j}\min C_{i,j}=-\sum_{i,j}\log(\pi_aM_{i,j}+\pi_bN_{i,j})=L
$$

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @drhab thanks for reminding me, I have updated the post and add the constraint in it.

Answer (score 1):

A comment about your log-sum inequality: it's just Jensen in disguise. Maybe  you can do something similar for other weighted sums of logs.

For $\sum_k a_k=1$, $a_k,b_k$ positive, WTS
$$
\sum_k a_k\log(a_k/b_k)\geq\sum_k a_k\log(1/B)
$$
where $B=\sum_k b_k$. Subtract the LHS above from the RHS:
$$
\sum_k a_k\log(1/B)-\sum_k a_k\log(a_k/b_k)=\sum_ka_k\log\left(\frac{b_k}{a_kB}\right).
$$
Because $\log$ is concave, Jensen's inequality says
$$
\sum_ka_k\log\left(\frac{b_k}{a_kB}\right)\leq\log\left(\sum_k a_k\frac{b_k}{a_kB}\right)=\log(\sum_kb_k/B)=\log(1)=0.
$$

Comment: thanks @Kim-Jong-Un, now I modified the post a little, is it possible to use this also to prove that minC equals L?

Comment: OP: sorry. I tried but it didn't work. Unless there is some further constraint, I couldn't see why $\min C$ would equal $L$.

Comment: there's only the constraint, that $\sum_{i,j}\Phi^{i,j}_a=1$, similar with $\Phi^{i,j}_b$, I also cannot figure out how to prove it, just trying to see if the condition that $\min C >= L$ holds or not